# Facebook C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am working on a ASP.net application and as extension I need it to be ported to facebook . I have searched for various documentation , including Stackoverflow ..But there is not much available to work through . I am good with ASP.net but  , is there anywhere a good documentation to read like Course 101 for developing Facebook application using ASP.net.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a "Facebook application."  It's my (possibly outdated) understanding that a Facebook application can simply be an iframe-ed web app hosted elsewhere, in which case you won't have a whole heck of a lot to do to convert it (maybe just stylistic work).  Much of Facebook's API is through JavaScript, so that's just as doable from ASP.NET as it is from any other server-side technology.

Answer (score 1):

The best is thing is to read the [official Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), and implement a solution using REST. The APIs are constantly in flux, so reading about which APIs are deprecated and which aren't is a realy good idea.

I'm not a fan of Facebook SDKs as they frequently break or are abandoned. It's beter to build on a technology based library like [`Hammock`](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Hammock) or [`HttpClient`](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/HttpClient). I wrote an article about this approach [here](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2011/07/facebook-integration-via-hammock.html) which might be useful.

Comment: why doing all by hand when a superb sdk is already created? http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks For info , Let me go through the writeup   .. Will surely update here .

Comment: @balexandre : Will the SDK , get updated as and when Facebook API changes ?? Trying to port something to facebook needs effort , and now each time the Facebook API changes these dll breaks ..When they are still in alpha and not even updated with comments from the developing team ...

Comment: the Facebook C# SDK does not need to change when facebook adds or removes features, as it uses the new `dynamic` type, you do loose the Strongly type way, but you gain a lot as FB changes stuff regulary and that will never break the SDK! I strongly suggest that you see the MIX Video that I mention on my answer.

Comment: @balexandre same reason I wouldn't use a third party to integrate with a SOAP service, it's an extra point of failure, and unnecessary. If the SDK truly has no strong types and is not coupled to the Facebook API, then it's just a REST library.

Answer (score 0):

## The official Facebook C# SDK is at Codeplex

> http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Is **stable** and **well maintain** , currenty at version 5.2.1 (Aug 23 2011)

The **[documentation](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation)** is also great!

---

I would strongly suggest that you take a look at the **MIX 11** video from [Jim Zimmerman](http://www.jimzimmerman.com/blog/) (creator of the Facebook C# SDK) at [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/)

> [**Facebook Development** in .NET](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN06)

Regarding Facebook itself, you really need to start searching because it always varies from what do you really want to do and what information are you taken / adding into Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Besides from the given ones, here is two good conference session videos for Facebook Development with.Net :

Facebook Development in .NET : 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN06

Building Facebook Apps with Microsoft .NET and Deploying to Windows Azure : 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX23

Answer (score 0):

Make your aplication in asp.net.Make a canvas applcation in facebook  and give the url of your application in he setings.
Link to make app: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: your application wll run o facebook by this way.Your users can aces you app in facebook by the name of your app.For eg: wwww.facebook.com/YOURAPPNAME

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest becoming familiar with Facebook's Graph API and taking a look at [Facebook's C# SDK (comes with a sample program](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk)) which was announced by a Facebook Engineer at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/.

Keep in mind that, last I heard, the SDK is an Alpha release so there may be issues. Be sure to report them.

Comment: Justin , this is my problem , there are no updates to the SDK , and its alpha release with no release schedule , Now if once we even start developing using it we have to keep track of Facebook API changes ..Is it not much of pain to rely upon ?

Comment: @thedotnetdeveloper - Their SDK really isn't all that complicated. It's pretty much a simple wrapper around a WebRequest that handles formatting parameters.

Comment: why are you using that api? the **official** one is at codeplex: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ and in fb http://www.facebook.com/csharpsdk

Comment: @balexandre - Nobody on that project is from Facebook. Not sure where you get "official" from. The link I posted was from resources at Facebook (for references: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/ ).

Comment: @Justin : Agree its not , what puzzzles me is the lack of updates on any of .net related facebook SDK ...You think relying on such things is OK ? ..Just curious ...Y there is not much of .Net related documentation. ALl the blogs i could google were like 2010 , Why there is not much of activity on facebook C#.net front :(

Comment: @Justin Niessner it's the official from **Microsoft** !!! http://www.microsoft.com/facebook

Comment: @thedotnetdeveloper - Two reasons that I can think of: 1) Writing Facebook applications with .NET just isn't all that popular (but definitely still done). 2) Working with both Facebook's REST API and Graph API is relatively simple. It's not hard to create your own wrapper classes to make the calls in .NET.

Comment: @Justin Niessner take a look at the Documentation and tell me if there's a simpler way Justin!! http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: @balexandre - So you can use the official Facebook SDK from Microsoft or use the Facebook SDK from Facebook. I personally would chose the later.

Comment: @Justin Niessner Facebook SDK ***wrapper* only exists** for **PHP**, **iOS** and **Android**, not .NET, you can only use Facebook Javascript API witch you can do plenty, but not all (for example, you can't remove the app requests id's), it seams that you never worked with ASP.NET and Facebook before, as you keep mention the same thing over and over and it's just wrong, with your rep size, you should know better.

Comment: and you keep saying the same ... THAT IS NOT THE OFFICIAL VERSION! It's just one guy that did something and it's not as good as the official one.

Comment: @balexandre - Funny...it's a post from Facebook developers and specifically says, "This is our first official C# SDK" in the post from the development team.

Comment: Andrey Goder works for Facebook, and the SDK is terrible comparing to the Microsoft version, I would never but my hands on Facebook "official" stuff in .NET, what do they know about .NET that is better than Microsoft? I rest my case.

Comment: I am actually a novcie to comment here , but the idea is same , if the Alpha Sdk Remains alpha how better we can use it ? Most of the blogs say its the one to use , but will there be any support using the same , I have not seen much of Javascript SDK but looks like as @balexandre has said ...the first page of facebook documentation says nothing about C# .Net  ..:(( ...